# Blender sculpting is not working

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, sculpting

I’ve been struggling to make Inflate work. Have no idea why it doesn’t do anything.
Have found no solution so far. Can you help me please to fix and make it work?

Only grab tool works.

[Project file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13G0iEtw9vK6hzqqBbAAalPh7lOIDdqUZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello could you please share the file that has the problem? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: In addition to moonboots' comment, consider posting screenshots too to help elaborate the problem. :)

Comment: @moonboots, i've added the project link

Comment: @Onyx, the screenshot won't show anything. That's why I haven't uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your brush settings (you've tweaked the *Stroke* parameters):

[image]

Increase its *Strength*:

[image]

Also in *Edit* mode select all and *Merge by Distance* with a 0.001 *Merge Distance*:

[image]

It works fine:

[image]

For the icing you need to deactivate the *Shrinkwrap* modifier, otherwise it will continue to stick to its *Target*:

[image]

Comment: This hasn't changed anything.

Comment: See my edit, I've alos merged by distance as you had overlapping vertices that caused bad shading. What do you mean by it hasn't changed anything? Please do the changes I recommend and share your file again

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. For the bottom this works. But for the icing not.
Well, I’ve spent the whole day to understand that the sculpting is not possible with low amount of polygons. I applied Subdivision to multiply vertices for the icing and everything works as expected.

Comment: have you disabled the Shrinkwrap modifier before? As long as you don't it will continue to stick to its target